# Angular 2 - Upgrading into rc4 throws script error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, angular2-forms

I have tried to update my angular  2 version to 2.0.0.rc.4 but its throws script error after performing npm install , npm start.

Please refer my package.json file below

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.4",      
"@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.4",    
"@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
"@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"systemjs": "0.19.27",    
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"zone.js": "^0.6.12",
"core-js": "^2.4.0"    
 },
"devDependencies": {
"concurrently": "^2.0.0",
"lite-server": "^2.1.0",
"typescript": "^1.8.7",
"typings":"^0.7.5"
```

}

below is my sample app.component.ts file

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';

 import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder,Validators,Control,ControlGroup } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
selector: 'ej-app',    
templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
directives: [ CORE_DIRECTIVES]  
})
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
disableDeprecatedForms(),
provideForms()
]).catch((err: any) => console.error(err));

export class AppComponent {

employeeDob: Date;
  constructor(private myform: FormBuilder) {
 }
```

This changes throws script error like below
[image]

Can you please suggest to update the angular version with no issues

Comment: Could you include your system.config.js ?

Comment: Hi, did u mean systemjs.config.js file. if yes i have included this

Comment: @SasiDhivya you must have missed entry for platform-browser-dynamic in your systemjs.config.js file. Please share systemjs.config.js file in your post.

Comment: Hi Sanket,      ' var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router',
        'router-deprecated'       
      ];     I have included this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your `systemjs.config.js` file. The location of the `.umd.js` files has changed to its own bundles folder:

```
var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade'
];

ngPackageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});
```

For further information, check the [**quickstart**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#wrap-up) guide of angular2